# How to Add another Propertys to User.Identity From table AspNetUsers in identity 2.2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

i Add some new property to asp.net identity 2.2.1 (AspNetUsers table) code first

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }

        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }


        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here

            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

Ok , Now I want to Call Profile Picture such as this code : 
User.Identity.ProfilePicture;

the solution is :

> You need to create your own classes that implement IIdentity and
>   IPrincipal. Then assign them in your global.asax in
>   OnPostAuthenticate.

But I dont know How to do this !! how to create my own classes that implement IIdentity and IPrincipal. Then assign them in your global.asax in OnPostAuthenticate.
Thanks .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have 2 option (at least). First, set your additional property as a claim when user logs in then read the property from the claim each time you need. Second, each time you need the property read it from the storage (DB). While I recommend the claim based approach, which is faster, I will show you both way by using extension methods.

**First Approach:**

Put your own claim in the `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` method like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // some code here

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("ProfilePicture", this.ProfilePicture));
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Then write a extension method to easily read the claim like this:

```
public static class IdentityHelper
{
    public static string GetProfilePicture(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var claimIdent = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        return claimIdent != null
            && claimIdent.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "ProfilePicture")
            ? claimIdent.FindFirst("ProfilePicture").Value
            : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Now you could easily use your extension method like this:

```
var pic = User.Identity.GetProfilePicture();
```

**Second Approach:**

If you prefer fresh data instead of cashed one in the claim, you could write another extension method to get the property from user manager:

```
public static class IdentityHelper
{
    public static string GetFreshProfilePicture(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        return userManager.FindById(identity.GetUserId()).ProfilePicture;
    }
}
```

Now simply use like this:

```
var pic = User.Identity.GetFreshProfilePicture();
```

Also don't forget to add relevant namespaces:

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

Comment: is there no way to actually get it from a property instead of a method?