# Adding extra properties to User.Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity

I'm working on an authentication app where we get a user's details from a WCF service. How do I add extra detail to the Identity object when we get all the user's details from the WCF service.

I would like to know how to add something like Email address to the identity object ie: `User.Identity.EmailAddress`.

Is there something in the web.config I need to add?

Comment: Do you have IdentityModels.cs file in your project? If so, edit ApplicationUser class.

Comment: IdentityUser already has an email field. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identityuser_properties(v=vs.108).aspx  You can additional fields as described here http://johnatten.com/2014/06/22/asp-net-identity-2-0-customizing-users-and-roles/#Extending-Identity-User---The-Easy-Part

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242574/how-to-add-another-propertys-to-user-identity-from-table-aspnetusers-in-identity/35246403#35246403)